What does the out put of config get notify / config get notify* mean in redis cli?
I was exploring spring session with redis and stumbled upon keyspace notifications. From browsing articles other than the official one I found out that we can use config get notify* command to get the current config.
So when I tried out in my redis instance these where the output
127.0.0.1> config get notify
(empty array)
127.0.0.1> config get notify*

"notify-keyspace-events"
"gxKE"

127.0.0.1> config get notify-keyspace-events

"notify-keyspace-events"
"gxKE"

So the problem is I'm not able to understand on how to output. K and E are for keyspace-events and keyevent-events from what I understood. So ideally the output of config get notify should have been gxKE alone
Why is notify-keyspace-events returned and what does it mean? And why is 127.0.0.1> config get notify* and 127.0.0.1> config get notify-keyspace-events returning the same output? When i tried to do 127.0.0.1> config get notify-keyevent-events it returned (empty array). Can someone please help me in understanding the output?
I went over the official documentation but im not able to find answer to my questions https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/use/keyspace-notifications/#configuration
